# OverflowError: int too big to convert with RSA encryption

Tags: python, python-3.x, rsa

I am doing RSA encryption using exponential, everything appears to be fine until I try to convert it to a bytearray for decryption `rst.to_bytes(8, 'big')`, it throws an overflow error, how can I rectify this?

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

def square_multiply(a,x,n):
    res = 1 
    for i in bin(x)[2:]:
        res = res * res % n
        if (i == '1'):
            res = res * a % n
    return res 

def encrypt_rsa(m): 
    key = open('mykey.pem.pub', 'r').read()
    rsakey = RSA.import_key(key)
    mb = int.from_bytes(m, byteorder='big')
    rst = square_multiply(mb, rsakey.e, rsakey.n)
    return rst

def decrypt_rsa(me): 
    key = open(pri_key, 'r').read()
    rsakey = RSA.import_key(key)
    rst = square_multiply(me, rsakey.d, rsakey.d)
    mb =  rst.to_bytes(8, 'big')
    m = mb.decode("utf-8") 
    return m 

def readFile(): 
    with open('message.txt', 'r') as f: 
        m = f.read().encode('utf-8')
        return m

if __name__=="__main__": 
    pub_key = 'mykey.pem.pub'
    pri_key = 'mykey.pem.priv'
    m = readFile()
    me = encrypt_rsa(m) 
    de = decrypt_rsa(me)
```

Comment: The first parameter to `to_bytes()` is the number of bytes to emit. If your message is longer than eight bytes, you'll get an overflow. You can try `(rst.bit_length() + 7) // 8` instead of the `8` you are passing currently.

Comment: Note, however, that this code will never give you a useful encryption scheme. For starters, it can only encrypt messages that are shorter than the bit length of `n`. It also doesn't apply any padding, so short messages can trivially be brute-forced.

Comment: You are also passing the wrong modulo in the `decrypt_rsa()` function – I think the last parameter to `square_multiply()` should be `rsakey.n`. (Note that the built-in `pow()` function also takes three arguments, so `square_multiply()` isn't needed.)